# Subquery returns more than 1 row - netbeans & mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

can you check my code?

```
INSERT INTO tbl_bed 
(status,wardID,roomID) 
   VALUES ('"+ cb_bedStatus.getSelectedItem() +"',
               (SELECT wardID FROM tbl_ward 
                WHERE wardName='"+ cb_wardname.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'
 AND category='"+ cb_ward.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'),
    (SELECT roomID FROM tbl_room 
      WHERE roomNo='"+ cb_roomNo.getSelectedItem().toString() +"'))
```

I got this error when i run the program "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Im using netbeans & mysql.

Comment: The error is very clear. Your subselect is returning multiple rows into a context where only one row/field is permitted. This has absolutely nothing to do with netbeans. It's purely a problem with how you've written the sql.

Comment: your select statement into your subquery clearly return more than one row which is not allowed in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_bed (status, wardID, roomID) "
    + "SELECT '"+ cb_bedStatus.getSelectedItem() +"', b.wardID, c.roomID "
    + "FROM tbl_ward b, tbl_room c "
    + "WHERE b.wardName='"+ cb_wardname.getSelectedItem().toString() +"' "
    +   "AND b.category='"+ cb_ward.getSelectedItem().toString() +"' "
    +   "AND c.roomNo='"+ cb_roomNo.getSelectedItem().toString() +"' "
```

if there is no risk of SQL injection attacks.  Otherwise, put the same SQL into a prepared statement.